# When might fix for flutter 3.19.2 /firebase incompatibility be available

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I had a working web app until 3.19.0 now after update to 3.19.2, then to beta, then to master and much googling and experimenting I need help:

flutter master channel 07mar2024 (commit?) not working with latest(?) firebase_auth

flutter run -d chrome
...
TypeError: Class constructor IndexedDBLocalPersistence cannot be invoked without 'new'
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 369:37
_checkAndCall
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 431:39  dcall
https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.0/firebase-auth.js 1:48595
_getInstance
https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.0/firebase-auth.js 1:144495
_initializeAuthInstance
...
hang

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a place to ask about product roadmaps or when next releases are available.  It's a place to ask about code that doesn't work the way you expect.  If you have non-working code, your question should show that along with your debugging details.  Otherwise, if you want a prediction about the future of some product, ask the product maintainers directly